# Add column to list of data frames and do incremental addition / Loop through df for simple addition

Tags: r, list, dataframe

I have this data frame (actually, a list of those dfs):

```
ALL <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = c("a", "b", "c"))
```

I want to add a column which adds up a certain value until the end of the data frame, like this:
0 + 0.05 = 0.05, 0.05 + 0.05 = 0.1, 0.1 + 0.05 = 0.15 and so on.

So, in my example the result would be

```
ALL <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = c("a", "b", "c"), z=(0,0.05,0.1)
```

I guess the way to go would be using cbind with lapply (assuming ALL is a list of dfs):
ALL<- lapply(ALL, function(x) cbind(x, z = ???))

But my brain simple doesn't come up with the right formula for z.

Your help is very appreciated.

Greetings

trumfnator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `transform` to add new column with `seq` to generate the sequence.

```
lapply(list_df, function(df) transform(df, z = seq(0, by = 0.05, length.out = nrow(df))))

#[[1]]
#  x y    z
#1 1 a 0.00
#2 2 b 0.05
#3 3 c 0.10

#[[2]]
#  x y    z
#1 1 a 0.00
#2 2 b 0.05
#3 3 c 0.10
#4 4 d 0.15
```

---

In `tidyverse` we can do the same by

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)

map(list_df, ~.x %>% mutate(z = seq(0, by = 0.05, length.out = n())))
```

**data**

```
ALL <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = c("a", "b", "c"))
ALL1 <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
list_df <- list(ALL, ALL1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this is what you want

```
ALL$z <- 0.05*(0:(nrow(ALL)-1))
```

Answer (score 0):

We can do an assignment and then return the dataset

```
lapply(list_df, function(x) {x$z <- seq(0, by= 0.05, length.out = nrow(x));x})
```

#### data

```
ALL <- data.frame(x = 1:3, y = c("a", "b", "c"))
ALL1 <- data.frame(x = 1:4, y = c("a", "b", "c", "d"))
list_df <- list(ALL, ALL1)
```